# jQuery - contents equal to rather than contents contains

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given the following html...

```
<div id="group">
    <ul>
        <li><div class="category">one</div></li>
        <li><div class="category">one</div></li>
        <li><div class="category">onetwo</div></li>
        <li><div class="category">two</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

...I'm trying to figure out how to make a selector in jQuery that will select all `'#group ul li'` elements that have a child `'.category'` with innerHTML equal to some string (eg. "one"). For example, given the string "one", this selector would return the first two li's.

Here's what I have so far:

`$('#group ul li')` will select all of the li's. Then I need to filter:
`$('#group ul li').filter(".category:contains('one')")` will select all of these li's such that they have a child with class category that contains the string 'one'. However, is there any way to check that this is ***equal*** to one?

I'm thinking maybe just write my own function that does the equality check and pass that to filter?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$('#group ul li div.category').filter(function() {return $(this).text() == "one";}).parent()
```

This is probably the most specific way. See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/68AeH/).

Comment: Your example doesn't return the expected results?

Comment: You wanted to get first two `li`s and it does exactly that. What is your expected result then?

Comment: Might have missed the .parent() at the end... my bad

Answer (score 4):

You can use the the filter function with a functional arguement.  Something like:

```
$('#group ul li').filter(function() { return $(this).html() == 'one'; } )
```

Comment: This is close, but the $(this) should be the checking the category child, not the this...

Answer (score 3):

None of the above answers are correct. I ended up using this as my selector:

```
$('#group ul li').filter(function() { 
    return $(this).children('.category').html() == 'one';
})
```

Please let me know if there's a better way to do this and I'll happily accept your answer.

Comment: Actually....Yours is just like the accepted answer, except his is filtering more specific up front, and yours is filtering more specific after. I honestly like the other better.

Answer (score 0):

would an if statement work, or are you looking for a selector? as statement, this might do...

```
if ($('#group ul li .category').html() == 'one')
```

Comment: I'm looking for a selector, I'd like to select many different <li></li>'s.